# deleting stopwords with Gensim

Tags: gensim, stop-words

I'm trying to learn Gensim using its site.
There is a function named 'remove_stopword_tokens' which is useful for my research.
Now, although the module is defined and is present on their website (exact link: [link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.html#gensim.parsing.preprocessing.remove_stopword_tokens)),I can't import it on my colab

Note: This is my code:

```py
import gensim
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopword_tokens

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-dbd838c83237> in <module>
----> 1 from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopword_tokens

ImportError: cannot import name 'remove_stopword_tokens' from 'gensim.parsing.preprocessing' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show whichever few lines of code are sufficient to get the error, and the exat full error received (with all lines of displayed 'traceback' etc)?

Comment: @gojomo I added my codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated & corrected answer**

You've run into a limitation of Google Colab - it may not have the most-recent version of libraries.

You can see this by checking what the value of `gensim.__version__` is. In my check of Google Colab right now (September 2022), it reports `3.6.0` – a version of Gensim that's about 4 years old, and lacks later fixes & addtions. The `remove_stopwords_tokens()` function was only added recently.

Fortunately, you can update the `gensim` package backing the Colab notebook yourself, using a shell-escape to run `pip`. Inside a Colab cell, run:

```
!pip install gensim -U
```

If you'd already done an `import gensim`, it will warn you that you must restart the runtime for the new code to be found.

Note that for clarity reasons you might choose to prefer using more-specific imports, as many project style guides suggest, rather than doing any broad top-level `import gensim` at all. Just mport the individual classes and/or functions you need, specifically & explicitly. That is, just:

```
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopword_tokens
# ... other exact class/function/variable imports you'll use...

remove_stopword_tokens(sentence)
```

On the other hand, if you want things simple-but-sloppy (not recommended), once you `import gensim`, it has already (via its own custom initialization routines) imported all of its submodules for you.  So you *could* do:

```
import gensim  # parsing & all gensim's other submodules now referenceable!

gensim.parsing.remove_stopword_tokens(sentence)
```

(Pro Python programmer style tends *not* to do this latter approach, of prefixing all in-the-actual-code calls with long dot-paths.)

Comment: I opened a new window on my colab and just run this line of code: `from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopword_tokens` , but again I received the same error! I don't know why it doesn't work on my system!

Comment: Aha! I just checked Google Colab, & for some reason they pre-install only a very-old version of Gensim (3.6.0 from 4 years ago – as you can see if you evaluate `gensim.__version__`). So if you only `import gensim`, you get that old version – which doesn't even have the newer `remove_stopwords_tokens()` function. But, you can execute `!pip install gensim -U` to update it to the latest version, then **restart the runtime** (as it will warn you to do in the output from the `!pip` command) so that the Python interpreter will see the newer version. After that, it should work.

Comment: I'll update my answer - the original ordering would've worked if the Gensim version had been recent, you *can* import more specific-things even after doing the `import gensim` (though stylistically it's still often avoided).

Comment: Yess.. It worked now!... but why colab hasn't updated the version!!?? it is weird!... anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: As wonderful as Google Colab is, there may in fact be no Google employee who's motivated to do the continuing maintenance of keeping default-installed libraries up-to-date. (Practically, there's always a risk such updates, if applied automatically or unthinkingly, it could break things... so inertia rules. I'm just glad they let users `pip install` their own updates when needed.)